# calculate week number from date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am so bad at this but i want to calculate the week number from date.
And what i found was this:

```
private int weekNumber(DateTime fromDate)
    {
        DateTime startOfYear = fromDate.AddDays(-fromDate.Day + 1).AddMonths(-fromDate.Month + 1);
        DateTime endOfYear = startOfYear.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
        int[] iso8601Correction = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5 };
        int nds = fromDate.Subtract(startOfYear).Days + iso8601Correction[(int)startOfYear.DayOfWeek];
        int wk = nds / 7;
        switch (wk)
        {
            case 0:
                return weekNumber(startOfYear.AddDays(-1));
            case 53:
                if (endOfYear.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return wk;
            default: return wk;
        }
    }
```

So this all looks great. But how do i use this on a textblock for exampel. Dont know this.

Comment: Is your question about calculating the week number, or how to use a `TextBlock`?

Comment: How do you number your weeks?

Comment: What would using a function that accepts a `DateTime` and returns an `int` have to do with a `TextBlock`?

Comment: Lets say that i have this:
    DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
    DateValue.Text = Date.ToString();

How do i use the weekNumber here. The textblock was just that i want to display it in a textblock so nothing more,

Comment: Did you even read what you just posted? Put in a call to get the week number between getting the current date and the point you're converting it to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments. You should find a better implementation for the weekNumber method. And rename to follow standard naming conventions. Consider making weekNumber() an extension method.

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Parse(MyTextBlock.Text);
int weeknumber=weekNumber(dt);
DateValue.Text=weeknumber.ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to keep it in the same style as what he posted so he can what he wanted. The code block is an example of how to do what he wants, it can certainly stand to be improved (for example, making sure it's a valid DateTime object, renaming variable and method names, using built in methods instead of making them up).

Comment: I tried this and its exactly what i was looking for. BIG thanks.